# aio_write on linux with rtkaio is sometimes long

Tags: c++, c, linux, asynchronous, io

I'm using async io on linux with rtkaio library. In my tests everything works perfectly, but, in my real application i see that aio_write which is supposed to return very fast, is very slow. It can take more than 100 milis to write a 128KB to a O_DIRECT padded file.
Both my test and the application use same I/O size, i check on the same file system (GFS).

I added counting and i see that there are about 50% of async io operations that are short (shorter then 2 milis) and 50% that are long (longer than 2 milis).

I also checked that the test and the application both use the same rtkaio library.

I'm pretty lost, anyone any ideas where should i look?

Another my related question: [/proc/sys/fs/aio-nr is never higher than 1024 (AIO on linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799537/proc-sys-fs-aio-nr-is-never-higher-than-1024-aio-on-linux)

Comment: I confess I know nothing about aio in practice. But this sounds like a good application for SystemTap. Specifically, you could have it display the full kernel call trees (there are example scripts for that), and you could even enable the tracing before the call and disable it right after. Along with timestamps, that should at least narrow down what is using up the time. (Sounds like it's hitting a fallback path for some reason and waiting on the write or a disk operation it decided to depend upon, but that's speculation.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to be discouraging, but I doubt you'll get a very useful answer to this question because there are way too many variables here (a cluster file-system, asynchronous I/O, `O_DIRECT`, etc.), and unless someone is very familiar with your setup in particular, the best anyone can do is give you vague advice.

I guess you should start by trying to determine whether it's the actual write that's slow, or whether it's the invocation of the async callback handler that's taking long.  You can try replacing the calls to `aio_write` with regular synchronous write calls.  Also, the write sizes you mention seem pretty small, so why are you using `O_DIRECT`?  I would think `O_DIRECT` would decrease performance here, if there are many small writes.

Comment: Yes, u r right, the questio is very specific. But i'm willing to accept any lead :). The i/o of 128KB is not that small. I'm measuring the system call to lanunch async io only, not how long it took to complete the I/O. I'm using O_DIRECT because i do not need buffering and because i have TBs of files. 10x!

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening the file with `open()` ?

Ensure that you're opening the file with `O_NONBLOCK`, and you're opening with `O_WRONLY`.

Comment: I'm not sure O_NONBLOCK is needed. aio_write/aio_read do not require it. I also open in O_RDWR mode, because i need to read and write. Can you please elaborate more why u think O_NONBLOCK is needed?